# Can I use SPDY protocol in windows8 metro app?

Tags: microsoft-metro, spdy

I am developing a Windows8 Metro app with Javascript and HTML.

Can I use the SPDY protocol in a Windows Metro app?

For example, If I use a dll that can speak SPDY protocol, via that dll,I can connet my app to my server.

My app uses so many network connection, so I want to reduce costs of network connect with SPDY.

My server can speak SPDY if client can speak SPDY.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your DLL can compile in the .NET Metro profile configuration, you should be able to use it.

**UPDATE**
I think the Chrome Metro App uses is as well. So you should be all good.