# Is Spdy ( speedy ) for windows available?

Tags: windows, apache, spdy

I have already searched for possible install of spdy under windows but no success until now.

Trying to install mod_spdy on apache under windows, official SPDY mod site provides detail for linux but no help for windows does anybody know how to set one up on windows 8 or 7 ?

If anybody is already using it, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920654/can-i-use-spdy-protocol-in-windows8-metro-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty) has a [SPDY server and client](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/spdy.html), and being written in Java works without problems on Windows.